# iText HtmltoPdf With Modal Dialogs on Page

Tags: itext7

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance. I am experimenting with iText Html2Pdf to convert web pages to Pdf documents.  I've run into an issue trying to convert pages that have jQuery dialog boxes.  When converting the pages, the Pdf displays the modal dialog in an always visible state.  I'm setting converter properties:

```
converterProperties.SetBaseUri("http://myBaseUrl");
```

Do I need to use some type of pre-rendering engine to handle this or is there a way of handling this within iText?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the contents of your we page. If it has JavaScript in it and that JS code affects layout, then you have to use a pre-rendering engine because pdfHTML does not support JS.

Comment: How would you recommend?  Use some type of browser extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question.  After a bit of searching and some trial and error, I end up using Selenium located at https://www.seleniumhq.org/.  With a few lines of code, I was able to grab the page without the dialog boxes showing and then converting it to PDF.